# Identify number of same/different edges between two igraph objects r

Tags: r, igraph

I have these 3 igraph objects:

```
g1 <- graph( edges=c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1), n=3, directed=T ) 
g2 <- graph( edges=c(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3), n=3, directed=T ) 
g3 <- graph( edges=c(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4), n=4, directed=T ) 


IGRAPH D--- 3 3 -- 
+ edges:
[1] 1->2 2->3 3->1

IGRAPH D--- 3 3 -- 
+ edges:
[1] 1->2 2->3 1->3

IGRAPH D--- 4 4 -- 
+ edges:
[1] 1->2 2->3 1->3 3->4
```

I want to compare the edges of g1 to g2 and of g2 to g3.  I want to count the number of edges that are exactly the same, the number of edges that are reversed (e.g. 1->3 changes to 3->1), and the number of additional edges.

Is there a simple function for doing this sort of comparison of edges?

How I do it currently is to get the edgelist and then do some row matching method to compare what exists and doesn't:

```
igraph::get.edgelist(g1) 
igraph::get.edgelist(g2) 
igraph::get.edgelist(g3)



> igraph::get.edgelist(g1)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    3    1
> igraph::get.edgelist(g2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    1    3
> igraph::get.edgelist(g3)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    1    3
[4,]    3    4
```

However, this seems long-winded. Is there a simpler way to compare two igraph objects?

The output for g1 to g2 would be:

```
same  reverse  addition
   2        1         0
```

and for g2 to g3 would be:

```
same  reverse  addition
   3        0         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's any less convoluted but you could use the intersection and difference operators in the following way,

```
u1 <- as.undirected(g1)
u2 <- as.undirected(g2)
u3 <- as.undirected(g3)

same=length(E(intersection(g2,g1)))
reverse=length(E(difference(g2,g1)))-length(E(difference(u2,u1)))
addition=length(E(difference(g2,g1)))-reverse
```

This will only work if g2 is a subgraph of g1, but it seems like that's the problem you've posed in the question since you are not interested in the number of edge deletions.